# How to customize Laravel's Collection API resources?

Tags: laravel

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

ArticleController.php:

```
public function index()
    {
        $articles = Article::latest()->paginate(10);
        return ArticleCollection::collection($articles);
    }
```

ArticleCollection.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class ArticleCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->title,
            'subtitle' => $this->subtitle,
            'cover' => $this->cover,
        ];
    }
}
```

This of transforming the model seems to work for a single model, but not for a collection. How should i customize which fields will be returned when working with collections API resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Let your DB query define the final fields

Check this way, in your `ArticleController` create a query with a `select()` method in which you define **which DB fields** are sent to the `ArticleCollection`.

**The collection will only take care of returning the that that was given to it!**

```php
public function index()
{
    return new ArticleCollection(
        Article::latest()->select(['name', 'subtitle', 'cover'])->paginate(10)
    );
}
```

**Result query**

```php
select
  `name`,
  `subtitle`,
  `cover`
from
  `articles`
order by
  `created_at` desc
limit
  10 offset 0
```

#### ArticleCollection

This file can be set as default, this allows you to dynamically set values passed from the `select()` method on the `ArticleController`.

```php
class ArticleCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
return new ArticleCollection($articales);
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. This is for working with a single model. I am trying to work with a collection of models and using the collection() method.